# Using Ray from Flask - init() fails (with core dump)

Tags: flask, ray

I'm trying to use Ray from a Flask web application.
The whole thing runs in Docker container.
Ray Version is 0.8.6, Flask 1.1.2

When I start the web application, Ray tries to init twice, at it seems, and then the processes crashes. I added the memory limitations later on because there where some warning regarding not enough shared memory size (docker compose setting is "shm_size: '4gb'").

If I start Ray in the same container without using Flask it runs well.

```
import os
import flask
import ray
from flask import Flask


def create_app(test_config=None):
    
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_mapping(
       SECRET_KEY='dev',
       DEBUG = True
    )

    # ensure the instance folder exists
    try:
        os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
    except OSError:
        pass
    
    if ray.is_initialized() == False: 
        ray.init(ignore_reinit_error=True, 
                 include_webui=False, 
                 object_store_memory=1*1024*1014*1024,
                 redis_max_memory=2*1024*1014*1024)
        ray.worker.global_worker.run_function_on_all_workers(setup_ray_logger)

    @app.route('/api/GetAccountRatings', methods=['GET'])
    def GetAccountRatings():
       return ...

    return app
```

When I start the flask web app with:

```
export FLASK_APP="mifad.api:create_app()"
export FLASK_ENV=development
flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8084
```

I get the following error messages:

```
 * Serving Flask app "mifad.api:create_app()" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8084/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
Failed to set SIGTERM handler, processes mightnot be cleaned up properly on exit.
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 331-620-174
Failed to set SIGTERM handler, processes mightnot be cleaned up properly on exit.
2020-07-06 07:38:10,382 INFO resource_spec.py:212 -- Starting Ray with 59.18 GiB memory available for workers and up to 0.99 GiB for objects. You can adjust these settings with ray.init(memory=<bytes>, object_store_memory=<bytes>).
2020-07-06 07:38:10,610 WARNING services.py:923 -- Redis failed to start, retrying now.
2020-07-06 07:38:10,675 INFO resource_spec.py:212 -- Starting Ray with 59.13 GiB memory available for workers and up to 0.99 GiB for objects. You can adjust these settings with ray.init(memory=<bytes>, object_store_memory=<bytes>).
2020-07-06 07:38:10,781 WARNING services.py:923 -- Redis failed to start, retrying now.
2020-07-06 07:38:11,043 WARNING services.py:923 -- Redis failed to start, retrying now.
2020-07-06 07:38:11,479 ERROR import_thread.py:93 -- ImportThread: Error 111 connecting to 172.29.0.2:44946. Connection refused.
2020-07-06 07:38:11,481 ERROR worker.py:949 -- print_logs: Connection closed by server.
2020-07-06 07:38:11,488 ERROR worker.py:1049 -- listen_error_messages_raylet: Connection closed by server.
2020-07-06 07:38:11,899 ERROR import_thread.py:93 -- ImportThread: Error while reading from socket: (104, 'Connection reset by peer')
2020-07-06 07:38:11,901 ERROR worker.py:1049 -- listen_error_messages_raylet: Connection closed by server.
2020-07-06 07:38:11,908 ERROR worker.py:949 -- print_logs: Connection closed by server.
F0706 07:38:17.390182  4555  4659 service_based_gcs_client.cc:104]  Check failed: num_attempts < RayConfig::instance().gcs_service_connect_retries() No entry found for GcsServerAddress
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7ff84ae8061d  google::LogMessage::Fail()
    @     0x7ff84ae81a8c  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
    @     0x7ff84ae802f9  google::LogMessage::Flush()
    @     0x7ff84ae80511  google::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
    @     0x7ff84ae5dde9  ray::RayLog::~RayLog()
    @     0x7ff84ac39cea  ray::gcs::ServiceBasedGcsClient::GetGcsServerAddressFromRedis()
    @     0x7ff84ac39f37  _ZNSt17_Function_handlerIFSt4pairISsiEvEZN3ray3gcs21ServiceBasedGcsClient7ConnectERN5boost4asio10io_contextEEUlvE_E9_M_invokeERKSt9_Any_data
    @     0x7ff84ac6ffb7  ray::rpc::GcsRpcClient::Reconnect()
    @     0x7ff84ac71da8  _ZNSt17_Function_handlerIFvRKN3ray6StatusERKNS0_3rpc19AddProfileDataReplyEEZNS4_12GcsRpcClient14AddProfileDataERKNS4_21AddProfileDataRequestERKSt8functionIS8_EEUlS3_S7_E_E9_M_invokeERKSt9_Any_dataS3_S7_
    @     0x7ff84ac4251d  ray::rpc::ClientCallImpl<>::OnReplyReceived()
    @     0x7ff84ab96870  _ZN5boost4asio6detail18completion_handlerIZN3ray3rpc17ClientCallManager29PollEventsFromCompletionQueueEiEUlvE_E11do_completeEPvPNS1_19scheduler_operationERKNS_6system10error_codeEm
    @     0x7ff84b0b80df  boost::asio::detail::scheduler::do_run_one()
    @     0x7ff84b0b8cf1  boost::asio::detail::scheduler::run()
    @     0x7ff84b0b9c42  boost::asio::io_context::run()
    @     0x7ff84ab7db10  ray::CoreWorker::RunIOService()
    @     0x7ff84a7763e7  execute_native_thread_routine_compat
    @     0x7ff84deed6db  start_thread
    @     0x7ff84dc1688f  clone
F0706 07:38:17.804720  4553  4703 service_based_gcs_client.cc:104]  Check failed: num_attempts < RayConfig::instance().gcs_service_connect_retries() No entry found for GcsServerAddress
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7fedd65e261d  google::LogMessage::Fail()
    @     0x7fedd65e3a8c  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
    @     0x7fedd65e22f9  google::LogMessage::Flush()
    @     0x7fedd65e2511  google::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
    @     0x7fedd65bfde9  ray::RayLog::~RayLog()
    @     0x7fedd639bcea  ray::gcs::ServiceBasedGcsClient::GetGcsServerAddressFromRedis()
    @     0x7fedd639bf37  _ZNSt17_Function_handlerIFSt4pairISsiEvEZN3ray3gcs21ServiceBasedGcsClient7ConnectERN5boost4asio10io_contextEEUlvE_E9_M_invokeERKSt9_Any_data
    @     0x7fedd63d1fb7  ray::rpc::GcsRpcClient::Reconnect()
    @     0x7fedd63d3da8  _ZNSt17_Function_handlerIFvRKN3ray6StatusERKNS0_3rpc19AddProfileDataReplyEEZNS4_12GcsRpcClient14AddProfileDataERKNS4_21AddProfileDataRequestERKSt8functionIS8_EEUlS3_S7_E_E9_M_invokeERKSt9_Any_dataS3_S7_
    @     0x7fedd63a451d  ray::rpc::ClientCallImpl<>::OnReplyReceived()
    @     0x7fedd62f8870  _ZN5boost4asio6detail18completion_handlerIZN3ray3rpc17ClientCallManager29PollEventsFromCompletionQueueEiEUlvE_E11do_completeEPvPNS1_19scheduler_operationERKNS_6system10error_codeEm
    @     0x7fedd681a0df  boost::asio::detail::scheduler::do_run_one()
    @     0x7fedd681acf1  boost::asio::detail::scheduler::run()
    @     0x7fedd681bc42  boost::asio::io_context::run()
    @     0x7fedd62dfb10  ray::CoreWorker::RunIOService()
    @     0x7fedd5ed83e7  execute_native_thread_routine_compat
    @     0x7fedd968f6db  start_thread
    @     0x7fedd93b888f  clone
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Best regards,

Bernd

Comment: Do you have two containers? Are you using docker-compose? You need to share a bit more about the setup.

Comment: I'm using one container, currently not using docker compose. The problem only arises when I try to start Ray "embedded" from the Flask application. Starting Ray as a separate server and just connecting to it from the Flask app works. Starting Ray embedded from a Jupyter notebook (entirely w/o Flask) runs, too. All this is done from the same container. Starting Ray as a separate process (or even in a separate container) is not such a big deal (might be even more manageable), but the API offers the embedded mode - why does it crash in this context?